# Save ASP.NET Chart Control output on server?

Tags: asp.net, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm just now getting familiar with the .NET chart controls.  I'd like to know if I can save the contents of a chart as a .jpg or similar file on the server.

I would like to be able to have the user download the file or display it to the user in a non-.net page.

I think it should be possible to do this.  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Chart.SaveImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.saveimage.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use this in asp:chart

ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"
 ImageLocation="~/your server path"

ImageType ="Png"

server path example:~/Images/TempImages/compare

compare is the name of image